# Is it possible to conditionally narrow a return type based on a parameter property that's not passed in?

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types

I think my code will show what I'm trying to ask better than the title:

```
export const objs = [
  {    
    name: '1',
    x: 5,
   discriminator: true
  },
  {    
    name: '2',
   discriminator: false
  },
] as const;

export type ObjName = typeof objs[number]['name'];

export type Obj = HasX | NoX;

export interface HasX {
  name: ObjName;
  x: number;
  discriminator: true;
}

export interface NoX {
  name: ObjName;  
  discriminator: false;  
}

const typeCheckObjs = (obj: readonly Obj[]): void => {};
typeCheckObjs(objs);

// I want this return type to be conditional instead of a union. Conditional on the objName's discriminator value
const howDoIDoThis = (objName: ObjName): HasX | NoX => {
  return objs.find((obj) => {return obj.name === objName})!
}
```

[You can experiment with this code in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQGMYDsDOyYCMBWmSAvEgNqhJIDeVVld6AhgLZgBcSA5AIxcA0DKhE4BWQSDoATAJaYUcGSxnME8TgjgBXMAwC%20EqrTpCkzNpy4AmAUNnzFy1eqQAzJgBtMuyUgOgAXSQmIjQsBABuUFBIWEQkBABPKDAkAHkCADlWVNIklJhXJDxCMnQtFlwwOACyLnMwLgCokBjoeGR81Iz8EiQACRCADSQAHyRMmCGWtrjkFQRq9xRUwcwR6gYGzh7sthbhTnLK6oOkewUlFSY1OA1tMBa9aPB2%20IWlphWJqZotnJ2WRyEXovgujmut047i8j1Bz1aIDC2ASyTAAGEABZgFAAax6RFIAAoSpw4GAmFIMB5EukCGQAgBKTgANxgMikJAAfDQ9C0ulicfiCJgSSLGTMQAB6KVIACSSAA7kx0J1MXIkOSEFo4OhUSkEjAkFVUBhZAgZBhPEgVNgKZzCsEkFp0Jb0AA6JDos0yC1WjzFPUIbHFIFsLhEcFXZxwJAszw6UDI5CYmCKgAiMDlmYAKurCUgxfg9hw6cWcsyBsMxj8RsQeZtfFqdXqSph3a4VFIiUXGdyaM3daH8O6GiRiKQSiW9IyAISgPRAA)

I'm wondering if it's possible to conditionally return the type in the last function? To do so, I'd need to associate `objName` back to the element in the list and figure out what type it is, then conditionally return that type.

I figure this can't be done for a few reasons:

1. The elements in that list aren't really these types according to the compiler.
2. It requires complex logic to associate the object name back to an element in the array.

If what I'm asking for isn't possible, I'm okay with tweaking the code in some ways. But I still want to be able to have the compiler check `objName: ObjName` for correctness.

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
const howDoIDoThis = <T extends Obj,>(objName: T["name"]): T extends HasX ? HasX : NoX => {
  const found = objs.find((obj) => {return obj.name === objName})!
  return found.discriminator ? found as HasX : found as NoX;
}
```

According to the compiler, the type signature is fine, but the last line doesn't compile.

[image]

I'm not completely convinced this type signature is saying what I want it to, anyway.

Here's another attempt with the same error message:

```
const howDoIDoThis = <T extends Obj,>(objName: T["name"]): T["discriminator"] extends true ? HasX : NoX => {
  const found: Obj = objs.find((obj) => {return obj.name === objName})!
  return found.discriminator === true ? found as HasX : found as NoX;
}
```

[image]

This compiles, but the error suggests it provides no useful benefit:

```
const howDoIDoThis = <T extends Obj,>(objName: T["name"]): T["discriminator"] extends true ? HasX : NoX => {
  const found: Obj = objs.find((obj) => {return obj.name === objName})!
  return (found.discriminator ? found as HasX : found as NoX) as T["discriminator"] extends true ? HasX : NoX
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would a `Discriminator` type with `Discriminator<typeof objs, '1'> = HasX` and  `Discriminator<typeof objs, '2'> = NoX` be useful? It can be constructed by mapping over the array. Getting `howDoIDoThis` to type internally might be a bit more tricky though.

Comment: Well, new items in that list will be added throughout the lifetime of the project. I'm not sure if that would work or not.

Comment: Are they added statically, as constants in your source code? If so, the mapping will take them into account, as it will return `HasX` for any child in the array that has `discriminator: true`.

Comment: @Oblosys I think so: they are added to the array at the beginning.

Comment: I've refactored it a bit and also managed to get rid of the `any` cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why conditional return types do not work**

When you tried to return a conditional type, you simply hit a design limitation of TypeScript - unfortunately, it is not possible to return a conditional type that will be resolved depending on a type parameter. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) in the repo for the discussion.

**Workaround**

A possible solution could be passing the conditional return type explicitly as a type parameter to the `find` method, but there is a catch. The problem (not sure if it was possible to do otherwise, though) is in how the `ReadonlyArray` interface is defined.

It accepts a generic parameter for the type of values it contains, so when it comes down to defining the `find` method, its type parameter `S` must be a subtype of `T`:

```ts
find<S extends T>(predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: readonly T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined;
```

Since your interfaces are wider than corresponding types of tuple members, union of them is not assignable to `T` because `number` (`x` property in the interface) is not assignable to `5` (`x` in the member type).

This can be worked around by taking advantage of declaration merging and adding an overload to the `ReadonlyArray` interface like this:

```ts
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  find<U>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: readonly T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): { [ P in keyof this ] : this[P] extends U ? this[P] : never }[number] | undefined;
}
```

The technique relies on `this` being inferred as a tuple which you can then filter for assignability to the resolved conditional type and extract the values that are left. Afterwards, you can tweak the `howDoIDoThis` signature to pass the conditional type through to the `find` method, and voila:

```ts
const howDoIDoThis = <T extends ObjName>(objName: T) => objs.find< T extends "1" ? HasX : NoX >((obj) => obj.name === objName)!;

howDoIDoThis("1"); //{ readonly name: "1"; readonly x: 5; readonly discriminator: true; }
howDoIDoThis("2"); //{ readonly name: "2"; readonly discriminator: false; }
```

Granted, this makes `find` look a bit weird when you do not specify the type parameter because `unknown` is now being inferred (this signature, being more lax on the type parameter, takes precedence over `S extends T` one), but it does not lose in inference:

```ts
const normalTuple = [1,2,3] as const;
const neverMatches = normalTuple.find<string>((b) => b > 3); //undefined;
const hasMatch = normalTuple.find<number>((b) => b > 3); //1 | 2 | 3 | undefined;
```

The only caveat, as you can see from above is that now you can pass an arbitrary type unrelated to the type of values in the tuple, but then the return type will be filtered down to `never | undefined` -> `undefined` which will be caught by type guards.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=82&pln=37&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAggIwFYwQXgQbVAhAbwIPxKgEMBbAUwC4EByARkYBoyCAPBgVg5AkAJgEsYYAE4iqIynAgSGcCQFcaZAL4CCxEpwSVaDRgCZ2nUeKky5ChgDMKAGxjrBCLaAC6CChkiwcADcoKBwAJ4ADjQIAPJoAHLUMdgR0RD2SGgwOFAqVMg0El44jIY0jF4hIKCycEWOYDEAEn4AGkRk5QzxqEm01dx8gwiWktKyFPKKCMpq1RqhIHUNFE0ICRAdhF3JdL39NEGk7mPWk9MOzq7HCKCLNctQ9RKNMQBKNBRC0E7hAIISCQUcIAHgAKgA%20TrueyyISggCqkIAFJEJDRRGApvQECiAG7ONQMcFsBDwmg8Az5QoSMkoVAMDHfX7hBDgnBeACUWGhKigAGsoBAAO5QMlwAAWYkBAHMAPwMChQcJchjEHAIAAK5KgCAFNHCGVm0owPiUppwWp8lPqUCEGERCHlJrEVvNBho%20KKHlyNKKPgAPgh%20UIaHCoJiFksAPQxhAASQQIuViClYgQGLgKgkerSMXkCEKCACojgImgzl18C%20QiQmQoIagFagADoEABhaBlltV6AmmIMw6MDBnCa2CQIQlONSgALwBCS0UAEQgCdX4NNWAQEIQtpo9owB2SqKHe3ZPMw0IZMFbEYR7L3XDtDoQACJmG-nQhWjAOgxNg6VEUQZS9rzQVtyiwTBsDPWguQAQmqUAlxFVd1wgTcxBRD83y5Y442IZkfigP4DHPXDjmI1kECpXgqNrGixxsKY7FmVQjg8FCVzXDdTRwkw8IImMiMY0i2W6d9BIYllxNGMRxhYy4EEcFxOIeOdoAXYUJCoZxwRUSInBSXBmDYEw2AAZh8PwSy04JNMCT1vQkABZKYwElGgMGwHS9KcAyjJoO94VBeApCgWVgOQMCiwQaFLPwhA41DcNZCjRyF0lPx3LgTztz8-TDOMkL7VBPICiKaLYuQeKEES4TmAQYMTGa%20q2tSiMMpAIA)

Answer (score 1):

If the names are unique and `objs` is a readonly array of readonly objects, you can statically determine the type by mapping over the array type. With a couple of utility types and a mapped type `FilterByName`, you can define a type `FindByName` like this:

```
type IndexKeys<A> = Exclude<keyof A, keyof []>
type ArrToObj<A> = {[K in IndexKeys<A>]: A[K]}
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type FilterByName<O extends Record<any, {name: string}>, N> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K]['name'] extends N ? O[K] : never
}

type FindByName<N> = Values<FilterByName<ArrToObj<typeof objs>, N>>
```

The idea is that we use `ArrToObj` to remove the array properties to get an object with string indices (`'0'`, `'1'`, ..) as keys and the array elements as values. With `FilterByName` we then set the values that have the wrong name to `never`, and use `Values` to extract the filtered object type.

We can now type `howDoIDoThis` by adding the signature `obj is FindByName<N>` to the find callback.

```
const howDoIDoThis = <N extends ObjName>(objName: N) =>
  objs.find((obj): obj is FindByName<N> => {return obj.name === objName})!
```

Applications of `howDoIDoThis` on existing names will get the correct type:

```
const t1 = howDoIDoThis('1') // t1: { readonly name: "1"; readonly x: 5; readonly discriminator: true }
const t2 = howDoIDoThis('2') // t2: { readonly name: "2"; readonly discriminator: false }
const t3 = t1.x // t3: 5
const t4 = t2.x // type error: "Property 'x' does not exist on type .."
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-POFUEjmBmdVQPCHaikLm5cXS6rh304wawGrc-nqtechrnW6PV0zSVMIOEyctyLxIsgGIwAA7gAIjA0qwS6GJyH0t4rmuRC7DknKivgpacJkDJcgw-4AHSuCoUiEjhTLFAQfpEJeUjvmwt5aty1BkggWhwJOJQkQ0JDEKQJSlnoDIAISgRgyIIDwfQQTBcEIUhIq8FwhEAPQaQkPCcLQZIUlSNKdgARDwJkREgBmUug1JICISCiJZ1lGecciXE4NwuJoOh+KAYEJFY8lQbB8EwIhciEtY6lIFpgV6VZ5I2XZplWBZiWGbZNKglczh3G4njeH5iLSZ0ADMfSySRECxdpCBlWI-mlQkAAslVWNVtUoiklbOi4JkAApwDAKSIDSXAQFw5wwE+ZgwMgkByDgk5SiRJEmaAQA)

Comment: If you're anycasting the return value of the function, you don't need any new code. The second attempt in the OP was already working except for the return type not typechecking correctly.

Comment: @Coderer That solution always infers `NoX` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn66xN)), which makes sense as it doesn't refer to `typeof objs`. But it turns out there's a solution without `any` as well.